# Show multilayer function relationship by cscope in vim

Tags: vim, cscope

I know source insight can show multilayer function relationship in one window.

For example, we have four functions as below

```
void example_A()
{
    example_B();
}

void example_B()
{
    example_C();
}

void example_C()
{
    example_D();
}

void example_D();
{
    return 5;
}
```

When I click `example_D()` in source insight, source insight show `example_C()` is calling the function.

Moreover, when I click `example_C()`, I see `example_B()` is calling the function.

The relationship is like this:

```
Example_D()
   |
   -->Example_C()
         |
         -->Example_B()
               |
               -->Example_A()
```

Could I see the relationship in one window by using cscope in vim?

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you absolutely want to do it in Vim and with Cscope if Source Insight already does what you want?

Answer (score 2):

CCTRee plugin for vim does this kind of visualization using cscope

https://sites.google.com/site/vimcctree/

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2368

https://github.com/hari-rangarajan/CCTree